# "add" event in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, addition, backbone-events

I want to use "**add**" built-in event in **Backbone.js** but I don't know how to use and what to put in **3rd** parameter of add (option), Can you help me?

as you know we use "add" like this -> 
"add" (model, collection, ***options***) — when a model is added to a collection.
my question is around option!
the second question is what does it mean to use "this" instead of *(option)* ?

Comment: try adding this.on("add", yourCallBack); it should work

Comment: @nikhilmehta as you know the structure of built-in event for "add" is 
"add" (model, collection, options) 
my question is how can I pass the "add" parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to understand how keyword **this** works in **javascript**. Wen I use one of available Backbone events, I put **this** as a third parameter:

```
this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
```

Comment: It does not matter even if you do not pass the third parameter as far as the trigger call is on the same collection.

Comment: @nikhilmehta then when should I use the 3rd parameter?
I search a lot and I get that they just sometimes pass (this) but what is the point of that?

Comment: @smokehouse can we use events of backbone on model or just we should use it on object?

Comment: @SaminFakharian you can use events on view of the model or collection. Maybe this video will help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTRy_GluLac&index=11&list=PLTjRvDozrdlwn9IsHWEs9IQv3HQob4bH3

Comment: @smokehouse onModelAddedd: function(model, collection, options) {
    console.log("options = ", options);
}
after a lot of search I get this .
but I can you help me where should I put this?

Comment: @SaminFakharian Your event function is wrong. if you want to define special function for event like _onModelAddedd_ you should do like this
`events: {
    "click": "onModelAddedd"
}
onModelAddedd: function() {
    console.log(this.$('.data').val());
}`
And string like this
`this.model.on('change', this.render, this);`
means that your view is listen to available event.

Look how i use events in my test app on backbone: https://github.com/smokehouse/backbone-task-manager/blob/master/js/app.js